# Poly() with raw=TRUE provides different result then I()

Tags: r, regression, poly

After running some polynomial fitting on wavelength data, I encountered quite different results for `poly()` with raw=TRUE enabled and using `I()'.

Some side-information: `ln` and `T_T0` are colomns of the fbg_data_simp dataframe

```
reg_fbg<-lm(ln ~ poly(T_T0,2), data=fbg_data_simp,raw=TRUE)
```

and

```
reg_fbg<-lm (ln ~ I(T_T0) + I(T_T0^2), data=fbg_data_simp)
```

Summary's from both variants:

[Summary view of top variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwNLF.png)
[Summary view of bottom variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDFE.png)

It's clear both results in very different terms. Any idea why this would be the case?
I am probably missing something.

Comment: Both R-squares are 1 and the coefficients are very tiny. Without the data it is hard to say more.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I think @G.Grothendieck's answer should solve your problem.  In future questions, you are (strongly) encouraged to post textual information (like your `summary()` outputs) as cut-and-pasted text (possibly in a code-format block), rather than as images ... it's much more accessible that way.

Comment: Thanks, for the tip! Ben

Answer (score 3):

`raw=` is an argument of `poly`, not of `lm`.

Comment: I tested it, and indeed you are completely right. Many thanks!